# Problem with booting after using boot-repair

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, boot-repair

I have dual boot Windows 10/Ubuntu 20.04 and I used boot-repair tool, when I wasn't able to boot into Windows. After it PC booted to GNU GRUB and I wasn't able to go through it anyhow. I tried to resolve this problem in some other way (converted from MBR to GPT using gdisk and created /dev/sdb5 bios-grub partition) but it complicated situation even more probably.

Motherboard: AsRock P67 Pro3

Log from boot repair (performed after conversion to gpt): http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/S3BnGXsrbP/

It recognizes OSes both on /dev/sda and /dev/sdb but I need only these on /dev/sdb to boot.

How should I proceed to be able to boot both OSes from /dev/sdb?

Comment: Windows only boots in BIOS mode from MBR(msdos) like your sda and only in UEFI boot mode from gpt partitioned drives. It looks like you had a BIOS Windows on sdb, but conversion to gpt will just break that install. With Multiple drives, best to only use Boot-Repair's advanced mode. If you want to boot BIOS Windows on sda, you need to reinstall a Windows boot loader to sda. You show errors on creating grub.cfg. Typo somewhere. I missed a } once, had same error. grub.cfg.new said error was on last line, and then difficult to find. Do you want UEFI boot or BIOS boot?

Answer (score 0):

You try to repair a broken system that is `EFI` with a boot from a `BIOS` disk this never works. In addition the sdb5 is not of the type `EFI System Partition` thus will never be used as such. It is way to small at 1M to be of any use as the `EFI` partition, the good news is you have a 500MB + partition where it should be at the start of the drive (sdb1) that can be re-purposed for the use as this partition.

First step is to boot with your windows media and do a repair of the bootloader files for it. Having removed the connection to the useless sda drive so it cannot in any way interfere in the process. You also need to have went into your firmware to make it a `EFI` only boot by using that setting disabling the `CSM`.

With your installer disk/usb now booted in `EFI` mode for certain. You first in `Terminal` do the following, `sudo gdisk /dev/sda` as the only disk in the system will be the one we need to work on with no power going to the former sda. When in there `t` then enter key, `1` then enter key, to select the first partition, next `ef00` then enter key, for the new type of partition this will once the `w` then enter key is used to write the configuration to the disk, changing the partition to what we need. All that is left is a `sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sda1` to format the partition as `fat` a requirement of the `EFI` boot specification.

Now when you run the boot-repair it should be in the proper mode and finding the proper setup for an `EFI` booting machine. If it is still not liking it then a  `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /boot/efi` before it runs should give it no choice but to find that and use it as the partition needed. If the install disk/usb has that already mounted then `umount /boot/efi` then the previous command to mount that one in its place.